# Updatable mirror of a svn repository, with read-only check-out

Tags: svn, repository, mirror

I know. The title is not very self-explaining. But here is the deal.

I have a repository in the company network (Subversion). We use this repository normally. I want to make a mirror of this repository in our cloud server.

The workflow Idea here is:

- Make this mirror in the cloud
- Client makes a check-out of this mirror
- We continue to make commits to the local-server-repo
- When we decide, make this changes available on the mirror
- client updates it's repository from the mirror

So basically, I want to make a easy way to the client to get the updates (this will be constant), directly from our cloud-repo, And I wan to to control when this repo will be updated from out local-repo.

Some things to keep in mind:
- No, can't open direct access to the client to our network (more about their security polices than from ours)
- Yes, I want to make this via 'svn-up'. Prepare a package will be 'more complicated', and updates will be constant.

Any idea how?

I've taken a look in svnsync and other tools, but I couldn't figure out how to make them do what I want.

Comment: Why does the mirror need to be an SVN repository? If it is read only then there is no point using source control and you might as well have a script that checks out the code to a web server directory that is shared. Subversion 1.5 introduced a proxy function which might help you.

Comment: Because I need to check-out and update from this mirror in the cloud.
I will take a look in this proxy function.

Comment: For set-ups with multiple repositories Git and Mercurial/Hg has been designed for. SVN is IMHO the wrong versioning system for that purpose.

Comment: I know. But the system already uses svn, I can't change that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.

I have searched a little more and found out that svnsync is what I wanted.

I followed these two links I got what I needed.

[Making a local mirror of a subversion repository: using svnsync](http://cournape.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/making-a-local-mirror-of-a-subversion-repository-using-svnsync/)

[Google Code - How do I import an existing Subversion repository?](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ#How_do_I_import_an_existing_Subversion_repository?)

The first sync takes a lot of time, but the following will only update the new revisions. And my client can make a checkout from the cloud and repos will only sync when I give the command to them do it.

Comment: Also, there's a configuration to do (described on the links) so the only user capable of modifying the repository is svnsync.